# whitespace hilighting on tabnew not working

Tags: vim

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /^\t*\zs \+/
```

However this config only works for the first tab which is opened at startup.
If I do `tabnew another_file` the leading whitespaces are not hilited in red.

How do I make vim to set these hiliting rules also upon creation of a new tab? I have tried autocmd on TabEnter event or BufNew event, but seems that my autocommands are ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried autocmd on TabEnter event

The tabs do not have matches or highlights, the windows do. So your event is, obviously, called `WinNew` and not `TabNew`.

Another problem is that your `highlight` will be lost after ColorScheme change. So, unless you're also going to catch `autocmd ColorScheme` and to harmonize your custom group with a new color scheme, whatever it is, you're advised to use one of the standard groups, for instance, `ErrorMsg`.